# Display content then manually refresh in PyGTK (2)

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk2

Having trouble understanding how to manually (I'm not using timeouts at this stage) refresh a window, or part of a window in PyGTK, version 2.

I want to display some information, in this example, a selection of output from the "df" command, and then be able to manually refresh the window, using a "refresh" button. I've looked at various examples and the PyGTK tutorial, but the exact place to put the refresh code escapes me. Tried using queue_draw in the "freedisk" function, in another function within that, in the "main" loop, without success.

I appreciate GTK3 is the preferred version these days, but I'd rather get this right, before updating.

The code for "freedisk":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pango, pygtk, subprocess, re, string, decimal, time
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

def yield_lines(data):
    for line in data.split("\n"):
        yield line

def line_to_list(line):
    return re.sub(" +", " ", line).split()

def remov_percent(col):
    return re.sub("%", "", col)


class freedisk:
    def getdiskfree(self):
        diskfreecmd = ['/usr/bin/df', '-hlT', '-x', 'tmpfs']
        diskfree = subprocess.Popen(diskfreecmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        return diskfree

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        box1 = gtk.VBox(False, 10)
        box1a = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        box2 = gtk.VBox(False, 10)
        box3 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)

        frame_1 = gtk.Frame()

        window.add(box1)

        diskfreedata = self.getdiskfree()
        diskfreedata = diskfreedata.replace("Mounted on", "Mounted_on")

        lines = yield_lines(diskfreedata)

        headers = line_to_list(lines.next())

        columns = [list() for i in range(len(headers))]

        for i,h in enumerate(headers):
            columns[i].append(h)

        for line in lines:
            for i,l in enumerate(line_to_list(line)):
                columns[i].append(l)

        j=0
        for i in columns[0]:
            j += 1

        title = gtk.Label('Disk usage and free space')
        box1.pack_start(title, False, False, 10)
        box1.pack_start(box1a, True, True, 0)
        box1a.pack_start(frame_1, True, True, 20)
        frame_1.add(box2)

        ucdiskfreedata = unicode(diskfreedata)

        label = gtk.Label(diskfreedata)
        label.set_line_wrap(False)
        label.set_max_width_chars(80)
        label.modify_font(pango.FontDescription("monospace"))

        box_sp1 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        box_sp2 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)

        refresh_button = gtk.Button("Refresh")

        close_button = gtk.Button("Close")
        close_button.connect("clicked", self.delete_event, "quit")

        mntlabel = [list() for i in range(j)]
        sizelabel = [list() for i in range(j)]
        progbar = [list() for i in range(j)]
        freelabel = [list() for i in range(j)]
        perlabel = [list() for i in range(j)]

        rows = [list() for i in range(j)]

        box2.pack_start(box_sp1, False, False, 0)

        rows[0] = gtk.HBox(True, 0)
        box2.pack_start(rows[0], False, False, 5)

        mntlabel[0] = gtk.Label(columns[6][0])
        freelabel[0] = gtk.Label(columns[4][0])
        sizelabel[0] = gtk.Label(columns[2][0])
        blank = gtk.Label(columns[5][0])
        rows[0].pack_start(mntlabel[0], False, False, 0)
        rows[0].pack_start(sizelabel[0], False, False, 0)
        rows[0].pack_start(blank, False, False, 0)
        rows[0].pack_start(freelabel[0], False, False, 0)

        for i in range(1,j):
            x = remov_percent(columns[5][i])
            y = decimal.Decimal(x) /  decimal.Decimal('100') 
            mntlabel[i] = gtk.Label(columns[6][i])
            mntlabel[i].set_justify(gtk.JUSTIFY_RIGHT)
            freelabel[i] = gtk.Label(columns[4][i])
            sizelabel[i] = gtk.Label(columns[2][i])
            progbar[i] = gtk.ProgressBar()
            gtk.ProgressBar.set_fraction(progbar[i], y)
            progbar[i].set_text(str(columns[5][i]))
            rows[i] = gtk.HBox(True, 0)
            rows[i].pack_start(mntlabel[i], False, False, 0)
            rows[i].pack_start(sizelabel[i], False, False, 0)
            rows[i].pack_start(progbar[i], False, False, 0)
            rows[i].pack_start(freelabel[i], False, False, 0)
            box2.pack_start(rows[i], False, False, 0)

            box2.pack_start(box_sp2, False, False, 10)

            box3.pack_end(close_button, False, False, 20)
            box3.pack_end(refresh_button, False, False, 20)
            box1.pack_start(box3, False, False, 10)

            box1.show()
            box1a.show()
            box2.show()
            box_sp1.show()
            box_sp2.show()
            frame_1.show()
            title.show()

            mntlabel[0].show()
            blank.show()
            for i in range(0, j):
               rows[i].show()
               mntlabel[i].show()
               sizelabel[i].show()
               freelabel[i].show()
            for i in range(1,j):
                progbar[i].show()

            refresh_button.show()
            close_button.show()
            box3.show()
            window.show()


def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    freedisk()
    main()
```

Edited (24.10.17) to add a simpler example then, just show the outputs of the command "ls":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pango, pygtk, subprocess, re, string, decimal, time
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk


class PyGlist:

    def getlisting(self):
        listingcmd = ['ls', '-1']
        listing = subprocess.Popen(listingcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        return listing

    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        # nothing here
        return None

    def processlisting(self):
        listingdata = self.getlisting()
        print (listingdata)
        loclabel = gtk.Label(listingdata)
        loclabel.set_line_wrap(False)
        loclabel.set_max_width_chars(80)
        loclabel.modify_font(pango.FontDescription("monospace"))
        return loclabel

    def refresh(self, widget, data):
        widget = self.processlisting()
        widget.queue_draw()
        return 

    def main(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        box1 = gtk.VBox(False, 10)
        box1a = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        box2 = gtk.VBox(False, 10)
        box3 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        frame_1 = gtk.Frame()
        window.add(box1)

        title = gtk.Label('Listing')
        box1.pack_start(title, False, False, 10)
        box1.pack_start(box1a, True, True, 0)
        box1a.pack_start(frame_1, True, True, 20)
        frame_1.add(box2)

        label = self.processlisting()

        box_sp1 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        box_sp2 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)

        box2.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)

        refresh_button = gtk.Button("Refresh")
        refresh_button.connect("clicked", self.refresh, label)

        close_button = gtk.Button("Close")
        close_button.connect("clicked", self.delete_event, "quit")

        box3.pack_end(close_button, False, False, 20)
        box3.pack_end(refresh_button, False, False, 20)
        box1.pack_start(box3, False, False, 10)

        box1.show()
        box1a.show()
        label.show()
        box2.show()
        box_sp1.show()
        box_sp2.show()
        frame_1.show()
        title.show()

        refresh_button.show()
        close_button.show()
        box3.show()
        window.show()

        gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pyglist =PyGlist()
    pyglist.main()
```

I'm getting closer to understanding now what's happening; I'm just slow at picking up concepts.

Comment: There's quite a lot of code there. You're more likely to get help if you can reduce that to a [mcve] that focuses on your problem. I suspect that you'll need to reorganize your code to get the behaviour you want. The `__init__` method gets called once, when the GUI instance is created, you can't just refresh the GUI and get it to re-do the things you want it to re-do. So if there's stuff in there that needs to be performed multiple times it should be in a different method, not `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in `processlisting` you create a new label each time, but you never add it to the widget tree, so it is never displayed. What you should do is reuse the label you already added in the user interface, and modify that one. Just pass it as a parameter when you connect to the `clicked` signal of the refresh button.

Also, no need to call `show` on each widget, just call `show_all` on the toplevel gtk window.

Finally, you only need to connect to the `destroy` signal to call `gtk_main_quit`. `delete-event` is when you want to intercept the user wanting to close the window and want to change the default behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pango, pygtk, subprocess, re, string, decimal, time
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk


class PyGlist:

    def getlisting(self):
        listingcmd = ['ls', '-1']
        listing = subprocess.Popen(listingcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        print listing
        return listing

    def on_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def refresh(self, refresh_button, label):
        label.set_text(self.getlisting())

    def main(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        window.connect("destroy", self.on_destroy)

        box1 = gtk.VBox(False, 10)
        box1a = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        box2 = gtk.VBox(False, 10)
        box3 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        frame_1 = gtk.Frame()
        window.add(box1)

        title = gtk.Label('Listing')
        box1.pack_start(title, False, False, 10)
        box1.pack_start(box1a, True, True, 0)
        box1a.pack_start(frame_1, True, True, 20)
        frame_1.add(box2)

        label = gtk.Label(self.getlisting())
        label.set_line_wrap(False)
        label.set_max_width_chars(80)
        label.modify_font(pango.FontDescription("monospace"))

        box_sp1 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)
        box_sp2 = gtk.HBox(False, 0)

        box2.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)

        refresh_button = gtk.Button("Refresh")
        refresh_button.connect("clicked", self.refresh, label)

        close_button = gtk.Button("Close")
        close_button.connect("clicked", self.on_destroy)

        box3.pack_end(close_button, False, False, 20)
        box3.pack_end(refresh_button, False, False, 20)
        box1.pack_start(box3, False, False, 10)

        window.show_all()

        gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pyglist =PyGlist()
    pyglist.main()
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'd tried variations of the queue_data line, but couldn't see that I was creating a new label each time, rather than updating an existing one.

Comment: Now it works, you can think about switching to GTK 3, and accept my answer ;). GTK 3 has been the stable version for years, and GTK 4 is on its way, so you should start now to get more up-to-date. Here are the official tutorials for python + GTK3 using pyGObject: https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Yeah, the solution to the simpler example works quite nicely. Original problem though requires the creation of a number of rows (hboxes containing label and progressbar widgets) to display the content of the "df" command. If a refresh is performed and disk volumes have been mounted/unmounted in the meantime, then those rows may need to be added to, or even removed. I've added another edit, including my more recent version of the "freedisk" program.

Comment: Then you should ask a different question, as this one focuses on the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I've cracked it, finally. Thanks to the help of the posters above.

The simpler example showed me where I was overcomplicating things.

The original program "freedisk" I finally got working, by moving more code into a separate function which made it easier to see what was happening.

Basically, the aim was to take the output of "df" and tweak it slightly with a hybrid text and graphical display.

Aside from any formatting boxes, titles, etc, there would be a VBox container with one HBox per line of "df" output, recreating some of the columnar output in text form, but with one column of progressbars.

The data translation and creation of rows I moved into a separate function.

This would be called initially, and then each time a "refresh" button were pressed.

Any existing rows inside the vertical box would be destroyed before the data was recalculated and then re-output. And this was where the final piece of the puzzle fell into place.

After destroying the widgets, and replacing them, I'd not realised they had to be re-"show"n. Adding one final line "widget.show_all()" solved the problem.